# Recover MySQL data from queries/logs/binary/whatever

Tags: mysql, datetime, logging, recover

I am having a very big problem with mysql. I have a form in which the users fill a field that corresponds to a datetime attribute in the database. The problem I am having is that the form had a bad format for the datetime field, and all the records are filled with '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in the database.

Is there a way I can recover the data the user submitted? Maybe from a log/binary log?

I have checked the general log and it is empty.

Thanks in advance! I really will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`mysqlbinlog`** utility can be used to convert the binary log binary format to text format.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html

Note that the binary logs may contain statements (those changes will be apparaent in the output from the mysqlbinlog urility. It may also contain binary changes, or they may be a mixture. What was recorded in the binary logs depends on the setting of the **`binlog_statement`** system variable. The default value depends on the version of MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log-setting.html

(This question might better be asked on dba.stackexchange.com.)

**FOLLOWUP**

The MySQL binary logs are not the InnoDB log files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1).

The binary logs (on one of my installs) are written to the MySQL data directory:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir'
```

e.g.

```
> ls -l /opt/mysql/data/mysql-bin*

-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1074553753 2014-05-28 22:39 /opt/mysql/data/mysql-bin.003907
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1073745289 2014-05-29 01:22 /opt/mysql/data/mysql-bin.003908
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  280683262 2014-05-29 01:55 /opt/mysql/data/mysql-bin.003909
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  520382482 2014-05-29 05:55 /opt/mysql/data/mysql-bin.003910
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  705774048 2014-05-29 15:26 /opt/mysql/data/mysql-bin.003911
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        817 2014-05-29 05:55 /opt/mysql/data/mysql-bin.index
```

Note that the binary logs are written only if binary logging is enabled. You can check whether binary logging is currently enable by querying the **`log_bin`** system variable:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin'

Variable_name  Value   
-------------  --------
log_bin        ON
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you know there the binary logs are saved? I have looked at /var/log but it does not seem to be a binary log there, nor in /var/lib/mysql. In the latter there are some files named ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1, but when I execute mysqlbinlog with them it tells me they are not log binary files. Thanks anyway!